# Does 0.5 x 1 x 1.5 ... result in a fraction or an integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series

You can assume the progression continues to some arbitrarily large number.

EDIT: Sorry, I had a brain fart. Changed the question.
Original: Does 0.5 x 1 x 1.5 x ... result in an odd number or even number?

Comment: Have you tried a couple of examples? What happened? Was the result even or odd?

Comment: The infinite product is neither finite nor an integer , hence it makes no sense to speak of an odd or even number.

Comment: Even if we look at the partial products, the best result is that mentioned in Matthew's answer (half of an odd integer), but shall we name such a number "odd" or "even" ? I am not aware of an accepted method to name fractions "odd" or "even".

Comment: Sorry guys, had a brain fart. I updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply out $2^k$ terms for any positive integer $k$, then there will be $2^{k-1}$ divisions by 2 and $1+2+4+...+2^{k-2}$ powers of two to multiply.  That will result in a net of one division by 2, so the product will be half of an odd positive integer even after we've multiplied by a power of 2.

This is not to say that the infinite product will exist, just to note that if $s_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{2}$, then no value of that sequence will be an integer.

Comment: Sorry dude, had a brain fart when I uploaded the question. Changed accordingly.

Comment: ... and answer accordingly updated!

Comment: Wow, that was elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The partial products up to any $n$ won't be integers. On the other hand, as a productory, it is divergent.